# Using WordUtils for class assignment

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm writing a program for a class assignment and I have a rather long string and I was looking for a way to do word wrapping, which lead me to the WordUtils.

However, as this is an assignment that my teacher has to review my source code and compile on their own system as a major part of the grade. Could I use WordUtils and still be reasonably certain that it would compile on my teacher's system?

Comment: Assuming that `WordUtils` is an external library, you'll have to ask your teacher if you're allowed to use external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will compile and run if (and only then!) your teacher uses the jar you yourself use as well as a library in his/her classpath. Which will not happen by accident.

So the safe bet would be to come up with a word wrapping algorithm **of your own** or specifically **ask for permission** to use external libraries for **non essential parts of your task**.

If unsure or not allowed you could still provide an *additional* solution with **detailed description on how to add the library and how to use it for running the task**.

Personally I'd like a student to be clever to use libraries and not to re-invent wheels. But again - only if the wheel wasn't your objective. Be sure however to explain about the library's license as well.